# Set element height to expand to the height of parent

Tags: html, css, height

I have something like this:

```
<section>
    <h3>Header:</h3>
    <p>My text which could span over several lines.</p>
</section>

section
{
    background: #5E5E5E;
    overflow:hidden;
}

h3
{
    background: #B31B1B;
    padding: 13px;
    width: 174px;
    float:left;
}

p
{
    margin: 13px 13px 13px 213px;
}
```

I want the header background to extent to the bottom of the section but when the text in the `<p>` tag is more than a line it doesn't.

What can I do apart from using the faux columns technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could absolutely position the `<h3>` instead of floating it. Something like this:

```
section {
    background: #5E5E5E;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
    background: #B31B1B;
    padding: 13px;
    width: 174px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 13px 13px 13px 213px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cZ3rh/

Absolutely positioning the `<h3>` can cause trouble if the `<h3>` ends up being taller than the `<p>` as absolutely positioned elements do not contribute to their parent's height:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NQB4n/

I can't think of a decent solution for this case right now though.

Comment: Because he is setting the position of top and bottom...i'd be interested to know if that's compatible with all browsers.

Comment: Compatibility was what I was thinking.

Comment: @Jared: [Box offsets](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props). Works the same in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera; should work the same way in IE8 and IE9, not sure about IE7, don't care about IE6. Here's another example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mEHM5/

Comment: Well, that answers my question. I didn't think `position` was that controversial, but I wasn't sure how it fixed the issue. It appears that, even if a child element, gives the `SECTION` a calculated height. Now, is the position property better on the `SECTION` or `H3`? :P (mu: Note as well that's my upvote.)

Comment: @mu is too short Works in IE7, doesn't work in IE6. But I agree with you - IE6 is dead :)

Comment: @Jared, @Webars: There is a problem if the `<h3>` ends up being taller than the paragraphs. I can't think of a decent way around that problem though, CSS's vertical sizing/positioning/alignment model is somewhat weak (I call it something else in private but I'm trying to be nice). Moving the backgrounds around suffers similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Can you apply the background to the `section` instead of `h3`?

Comment: Simplicity - I should be able to get ideas like that, I'll give it a go and let you know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Just to let you know, this method did work but the guy that just posted was a better solution in my opinion. I gave an upvote anyways for a working and least-edits-needed solution.

Comment: @Ben - *Least edits necessary* isn't always the best way forward, but I agree, mu's answer is interesting. I think his actually answers the question, instead of a workaround (which may be a better way overall).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be to move the background to the `SECTION` and `P` tags.

```
section {
    background: #B31B1B;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

h3 {
    padding: 13px;
    width: 174px;
    float:left;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    background: #5E5E5E;
    padding: 13px;
    margin-left: 213px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pEfGq/

Comment: Note, I was working on this answer (and others) before I saw Webars answer.

Answer (score 1):

give a try to min-height = 100% in h3!

Comment: but you have to specify the height parameter for the section element though!

Comment: Ah right...thanks for the reply but the section height is not (and can't be) set.

Answer (score 1):

just set height of the h3 element to 100%.

```
h3
{
      background: #B31B1B;
      padding: 13px;
      width: 174px;
      float:left;
      height: 100%;
}
```